# Dotnetopenauth CTP v4 - Using Password workflow

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I have a client who wants to use Oauth 2 however they want handle the passwords at their end due to the way their systems work (long story).I believe there is an oauth workflow that supports this. Would dotnetopenauth support this? Cheers, Chris. I will be designing a provider for them to use.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the OAuth 2 spec, DNOA will very likely support it when the spec is finalized and DNOA releases a new version that implements it.

Personally, I very much dislike that particular workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does DNOA CTP not support it currently. Is there a timeframe for when DNOA will release v4. I have a client who is insistant on Oauth 2 and the password workflow. I'm not an expert but the password workflow seems to defeat the point of Oauth.

Comment: Yes, it defeats nearly the whole point of OAuth.  The only point that remains is that *if* the client does it properly the password doesn't end up getting stored in persistent storage, but only the oauth token is.  That's better than the password -- slightly.  But you're still training the user to share his/her secret with a 3rd party, and that's bad.  As for when DNOA will support the password flow, probably 1-3 months away.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -Pre gives me an error: Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Pre'.

Comment: @Picflight can you double-check that you have the latest version of nuget installed?